# Identifying a two numbers SMD capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification, surface-mount

On [this board](https://framapic.org/Pabb4fEqmNTH/AefULlP4sLut.jpg), I'm trying to identify the burned component, which I believe might be a capacitor.
When [zooming in](https://framapic.org/gallery#59rIBBtds8d1/6AQDRhLyfVYO.JPG,FGnyB17m7Lca/IhaO4JcrQ2TM.JPG,TacdbWnENLmS/GMS8IkGHgK4J.JPG,BU67fM6Yc97T/OtEQUYOKghJA.JPG,4o77NbprNtM8/pB887Oxi7UUc.JPG,jSs6fTUCIUzf/9EnpUuAfrfFW.JPG,2g6kRu3VzqRu/VFpySlaq5JZ8.JPG,nHguZ0LT0BH9/zcEPfgPFhKBM.JPG), I think I recognize "47" written on the first line, and maybe "16V" on the line below. This board is powered by a 15V power supply.

I don't know if it's a capacitor. It might be, because the empty space nearby (which was empty when disassembling) could have been a replacement for a non-SMD version of the capacitor, and it's labeled "C1".

I don't know what 47 means.
Is it 47µF?
Is it .47µF?
Is it 47pF?

With only 2 numbers, I can't read it.

May you give me some hints please?

Answer (score 4):

It was a 47uF 16V tantalum capacitor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask you to confirm that when only two numbers are written, it means that this value is in µF ?

Comment: Thanks again for your help : you were indeed right, and it helped me to fix my issue.
For the long story, here is what it was about :
[https://bricolage.ecarnot.net/robopong/](https://bricolage.ecarnot.net/robopong/) So sorry it's written in french, but the bottom of the page will make you understand. Thanks again, and have a nice day. Nicolas